# animated search form with close button

Tags: html, css, animation, button, search

I'm want to use animated search form from w3schools example

```
input[type=text] {
  width: 130px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url('searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
</form>
```

problem is that it doesn't have close button, how can i insert close bitton which will be visible only after expanding?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bL2mpsx0/ here it is